# VIM - "Pretty" column format of structs in C

Tags: regex, vim, formatting, indentation, col

I have some C code with a lot of `typedef`'ed `struct`s, and look like so in VIM:

```
typedef struct {
  int         a;
  someValue*    b;
  someOtherValue* c;
} val_t;
```

When I enable "print whitespace characters" in VIM via `:set list`, I see the code appears like so (with `.` characters denoting spaces, and `-->` denoting hard tabs):

```
typedef struct {
  int->-->-->-->a;
  someValue*....b;
  someOtherValue*>>c;
} val_t;
```

So, it seems like this code has a mix of hard-tabs and spaces all over the place, likely due to different editors being used to maintain it. I'm attempting to write some commands to tidy it up. I know I can do a visual selection via <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then pipe off the selection to `col` via:

```
:'<:'>!col
```

However, the output in VIM looks terrible, as it seems `col` is just separating the columns "logically" (ie: via three hard-tabs), rather than lexically, and the output looks like so:

```
typedef struct {
  int--->--->--->a;
  someValue*>--->--->b;
  someOtherValue*--->--->--->c;
} val_t;
```

Is there a way to tell `col` to align the columns of data using hard-tabs of a fixed width (ie: 4 "spaces" per tab) as shown below, so that the beginning of the variable names within the struct visually align? The desired result would be:

```
typedef struct {
  int--->--->--->--->a;
  someValue*>--->--->b;
  someOtherValue*--->c;
} val_t;
```

This would allow me to re-factor a bunch of header files on a per-block/per-struct level rather than spending hours manually indenting chunks of code to look nice.

Thank you.

Comment: I think typed code can be pretty loose with formatting. Whats to stop it finding/acting on something like `"\t  someValue \t* \tname\n\n\t ;"` ? Is it smart enough?

Comment: I could just swap tabs with spaces via `s/\t/ /g` and then replacing consecutive delimiters with a single one via `s/\t\{1,\}/\t/g`. That means I know I'm just looking for two fields separated by a single tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you stuck on hard tabs? If not you may want to look into [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) or [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align).

With tabular you can do something like this:

```
:?{?+,/}/-Tabularize/\ze\w\+;/
```

For more help see:

```
:h \ze
:h range
```

Comment: I'm stuck using hard tabs so it renders properly on other editors.

Comment: This is the exact reason to use spaces. Change `'tabstop'` to 4 (e.g. `set ts=4`) and then 8 in your example. It will change if they align or not. Using tabs for indention will be fine, but for aligning would cause issues. Using spaces solves this problem completely.

Comment: I agree with your statement, but I am currently forced to use a setup which uses hard-tabs which are 4 spaces wide, as are all other people working on the same project.

Comment: The above answer works, and probably better than a shell script function I wrote to achieve the same functionality, so marking as accepted. Thanks!